# Is it possible to run android application without emulator and android phone

Tags: android

I am using Android Studio, my system  does not support emulator and I don't have any android phone but I want run android application. Is it possible to run android application without emulator and android phone?

Comment: What kind of system do you have?

Comment: you need an Android emulator or Android device to run Android APK files

Comment: i am using windows7 os,processor is intel dual core processor(and it does not support virtualization)

Answer (score 1):

No.  It does not make sense that you would be able to do so, every application for any device needs a platform to run on!

More importantly, why do you say your system does not support emulators?  There are many free emulators available online, I personally recommend you try [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/).

**UPDATE:**  My guess is that the error you are getting is due to your computer hardware not supporting multiple CPUs such as those found in modern android phones.  It *might* be possible to turn on hardware virtualization in your computer BIOS (usually you press F2 or some such when you are booting up - but this depends on your particular hardware).

The *very first* thing I would try before anything else is to download Genymotion (as it was also recommended by the other answers), and at least one other emulator before giving up.  Have you tried any other emulator other than the default one that comes with Android Studio?  Different emulators likely work differently and they might not need hardware virtualization.

Comment: while running emulator it show's:Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!

Comment: while installing HAXM software it showing " your computer does not support inter virtualization technology."      may be my system configuration not supported

Comment: I have updated my answer given your new information.

Comment: Thank you Ivan, I will try genymotion

Answer (score 1):

There are different emulators. You can try installing [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/). You need an emulator or an android phone to run your app

Comment: Good recommendation, GenyMotion worked for my friend who didn't have a phone. But native libs didn't work properly, however.

Comment: my computer does not support  virtualization technology

Answer (score 1):

You will always need to deploy your applications on Android OS which is only possible on an emulator or Android-phone when developping native-apps. If you're developing hybride applications, you can run your app in a browser and use browser-plugins to simulate the native features of your device. Please keep in mind that there is more than 1 emulator available for Android. The emulator in Android Studio is one of the slowest available. Try using genymotion or BlueStacks, but preferably, Genymotion.

Comment: my computer does not support  virtualization technology

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to use the HAXM based emulator or Genymotion, you are better off buying a handset device.

Otherwise you are limited to running the ARM based emulation which in the SDK manager looks like 'ARM EABI v7a System Image'. The ARM based emulation should be used with GPU acceleration enabled. Best possible performance would be to use the smallest screen possible such as 480x320, 800x480 or 854x480. The larger the screen in terms of pixels, the worse the performance.

Again the best recommendation is to get a Android phone/tablet and do your development there.